# Production vs Dev Server Javascript Function not Defined Error

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I have an html section that looks like this

```
<span onclick="like_logic(this)">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-lg" hx-post="/update_like/{{posts[i][6]}}" hx-trigger="click" hx-target="#like_location{{i}}" hx-swap="innerHTML" id="like_button_{{i}}">                                                                                                           
    <span id="like_location{{i}}">
        {{posts[i][7]}}
        {{likes}}
    </span>
    </button>
</span>
```

And a javascript section that looks like this:

```
function like_logic(value){
        let tag = value.firstChild.nextElementSibling;
        console.log(tag)
        
        if ( $(tag).hasClass("btn btn-outline-danger")){
            console.log("1")
            $(tag).removeClass("btn btn-outline-danger");
            $(tag).addClass("btn btn-outline-dark");  
        }
        else{
            console.log("2")
            $(tag).removeClass("btn btn-outline-dark");
            $(tag).addClass("btn btn-outline-danger");  
        }
    }
```

It's just supposed to change the color at the same time as using htmx to update the backend at the same time, this works fine in my dev encironment, but when I'm in production I get

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: like_logic is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick
```

Anyone know what might be causing that? Thanks for your time.

Comment: are there any errors logged into your console?  it seems like your script is not loading at all or, it is loading at the wrong time, that being too late...

Comment: @ThisGuy the only log in the console is this one "Uncaught ReferenceError: like_logic is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick"

Comment: Does the Scripts tag of the console show that the script that defines the function is loaded?